# Simple counter with a listener and callback

Tags: javascript, callback, listener

I have a simple class below that starts and then updates a count every second. How would I go about adding functionality for it to listen for a specific value and then fire a callback?

```
function Counter() {
    this.currentCount = 0;
}

Counter.prototype.start = function() {
    setInterval(this.update, 1000);
};

Counter.prototype.when = function(value, callback) {
    callback(value);
};

Counter.prototype.update = function() {
    this.currentCount++;
};
```

In my mind it would work something like this.

```
var counter = new Counter();
counter.when(50, function(value) {
    console.log('We arrived at ' + value + ', the requested value.');
});
counter.start();
```

Comment: what value are you looking for? elapsed time ? html input ?...

Comment: well in this example it would just return value originally asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a nice homework, I'll do that for you ;) Please have a look on my solution:

```
function Counter() {
    this.currentCount = 0;
    this.conditions = [];
    this.interval = undefined;
}

Counter.prototype.start = function() {
    if (!this.interval) {
        var that = this;
        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            that.update();
        }, 1000);
    }
};

Counter.prototype.stop = function () {
    if (this.interval) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.interval = undefined;
    }
    this.currentCount = 0;
};

Counter.prototype.when = function(value, callback) {
    var that = this;
    this.conditions.push(function () {
        if (that.currentCount === value) {
            callback.call(that, value);
        }
    });
};

Counter.prototype.update = function() {
    this.currentCount++;
    for (var i = 0, l = this.conditions.length; i < l; i++) {
        var condition = this.conditions[i];
        condition();
    }
};

var counter = new Counter();
counter.when(50, function(value) {
    console.log('We arrived at ' + value + ', the requested value.');
});
counter.when(60, function (value) {
    console.log('Stop at ' + value + '!');
    this.stop();
});
counter.start();
```

and it's [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/6w2DR/1/)!

Another answer here made a good argument in hiding private variables, but implemented it a bit too confused, so this is another way of doing it similar. Instead of shared prototype functions this is using instance functions. Some may say this needs more memory, but I don't believe it's significant, and allows to easily have privates in a real constructor function.

```
var Counter = function () {
    var that = this, currentCount = 0,
        conditions = [], interval;
    var update = function () {
        currentCount++;
        for (var i = 0, l = conditions.length; i < l; i++) {
            var condition = conditions[i];
            condition();
        }
    };
    this.start = function () {
        if (!interval) {
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                update.call(that);
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
    this.when = function (value, callback) {
        conditions.push(function () {
            if (currentCount === value) {
                callback.call(that, value);
            }
        });
    };
    this.stop = function () {
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = undefined;
        }
        currentCount = 0;
    };
};

var counter = new Counter();
counter.when(50, function(value) {
    console.log('We arrived at ' + value + ', the requested value.');
});
counter.when(60, function (value) {
    console.log('Stop at ' + value + '!');
    this.stop();
});
counter.start();
```

see it [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ejHZW/1/)!

Notice also that in both examples, `counter` is `instanceof Counter` and `Object`,
whereas `Counter` is `instanceof Function` and `Object` (why I like to write so much code ;))

Comment: Nice, I need to study and play with this a little bit more. I like that it can hold multiple conditions.

Comment: i hope you don't get confused by `that` and `callback.call` - `that` is required, because in nested functions the `this` is not "the counter" object. it makes the callback having `this === that` (the counter). as you see in the setInterval function, i actually use `that.update`, so `update` is already called "in context of `that`" and there's no more need to do `that.update.call(that)`. i contrast to directly `setInterval(this.update, 0)` you would loose `this`. WAH weird to explain, but easy when you read about Function's call and apply.

Comment: I'm not confused by it, if using lodash/underscore I think it could also be binded. I agree it can be hard to explain, but your example almost explains itself.

Comment: Well thanks ;) Beware of bind, it eliminates the prototype's this. If you create multiple Counters and each does bind its instance to update, only the last bound Counter is used! prototype functions are shared, unique for all instances!

Answer (score 0):

To support multiple whens:

Add an array of whens in your class:

```
function Counter() {
    this.currentCount = 0;
    this.whens = [];
}
```

Then let the when function push to that:

```
Counter.prototype.when = function(value, callback) {
this.whens.push({'time' : value, 'callback' : callback});
}
```

And check for these whens at update:

```
Counter.prototype.update = function() {
    this.currentCount++;

    for(var w in this.whens) {
        if(this.currentCount == this.whens[w].time) {
            this.whens[w].callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like:

```
function Counter(interval, val, func){
  this.currentCount = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    this.currentCount++;
    if(this.currentCount === val)func();
  }, interval);
}
var nc = new Counter(1000, 50, function(){
  console.log('We have arrived at '+nc.currrentCount);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an argument to be made for something like this instead:

```
var Counter = (function() {
    var update = function() {
        var idx, callbacks;
        this.currentCount++;
        callbacks = this.callbacks[this.currentCount];
        if (callbacks) {
            for (idx = 0; idx < callbacks.length; idx++) {
                callbacks[idx](this.currentCount);
            }
        }
    };
    var start  = function() {
        var counter = this;
        setInterval(function() {update.call(counter)}, 1000);
    };
    var when = function(count, callback) {
        (this.callbacks[count] || (this.callbacks[count] = [])).push(callback);
    };
    return function() {
        var config = {currentCount: 0, callbacks: {}};
        this.start = function() {return start.call(config);};
        this.when = function(count, callback) {
            return when.call(config, count, callback);
        };
        // this.stop = ... // if desired
    };
}());
```

This is somewhat more memory intensive than the prototype-based version of the code.  I wouldn't use it for something where you were expecting hundreds of thousands or millions of objects.  But it has the advantage that it truly encapsulates the data you might like to keep hidden, such as `currentCount` and the list of callbacks.  It doesn't expose an unnecessary `update` function.  And it's not *terribly* more heavy than the prototype version.  Each instance has its own `start` and `when` functions, but those are just thin wrappers around common functions.

It is a bit more difficult to add a `stop` function to this in the same manner, unless you don't mind exposing the the result of `setInterval`.  But it is doable.

Comment: I like the argument to hide privates, but I think you made it a bit too complicated. Don't return an anonymous function, but use the constructor function more: create private `var counter = this, currentCount = 0, conditions = {}, interval;` and then just expose `this.start` and `this.when`, leaving `var update`. Then you can also easily add `this.stop` and you got a real constructor function, not exposing the currentCount, update etc!

Comment: see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VeJG2/) for how I think to implement it that way, as a constructor function with privates and instance instead of prototype shared functions

Comment: @metadings: Yes, this technique works equally well to hide the private data.  The reason I use the one I chose is to reduce memory footprint a bit of each Counter object.  In your version, each `Counter` has entire copies of the `start` and `when` functions; in mine, they have only thin wrapper functions around common functions.  This is probably less important with such small functions, but it can make a difference in some cases.  I realized too that I was silly about `stop`.  It was easy to implement here: http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/m9Xs2/

Comment: ah now i get how you thought, you made a sort of private prototype scope; however i can't simply agree, i believe it's going to be very confusing because of the scope of vars and the calls with config (as this, instead of this (instance)of the constructor function); it's not wrong but in this case i would prefer easier-to-read-code instead of lower footprint; since jits precompile the code, it should not be that big impact

Comment: @metadings: It is of course a matter of choice.  This is one attempt to increase the encapsulation without sacrificing too much memory.  Your alternative also increases the encapsulation, with somewhat simpler code but requiring more memory.  (Precompiling has nothing to do with this, though.  This has to do with the memory per instance.  Yours has a separate `update`, `start`, and `when` function for each instance.  Mine has only thin wrapper functions for `when` and `start` on each instance.)  But it's an optimization the OP may not be at all interested in pursuing.